# Astable 555 Timer creates longer pulse when just turned on

Tags: timer, 555, pulse, astable

I have a question regarding the behavior of a 555 timer circuit that I have made. It is depicted below.

[image]

Now, here is some interesting behavior, I wrote a program on arduino that measures the lengths of the pulses from this 555 timer. Here is the output that I had.

```
  Was on for: 472
  Was on for: 279
  Was on for: 279
  Was on for: 277
  Was on for: 278
  Was on for: 278
  Was on for: 278
  Was on for: 279
  Was on for: 277
  Was on for: 278
  Was on for: 278
  Was on for: 277
```

Now, as you can see, when the 555 timer is first turned on, the pulse is much longer (measured in milliseconds). My question is, how would I avoid this behavior? In other words, how can I turn an astable 555 timer on and off and have the first pulse be the same length as all of the other ones?

Comment: Does anyone else feel that on calculation last pulse deviates just too much from actual answer that is around 303ms. And value of control capacitor is too high.

Comment: @manav.tix, that last pulse is an anomaly because I turned off the circuit, I will remove from the question since it is confusing.

Comment: I tried the solution with .47,0.047 uf caps and it does Not work... am i missing something or simply it does not work...

Comment: @Bulent  If you have a question please ask it as a new question. Note that the added cap should be 50% of the size of the timing cap used. Your is 10% - which will make some difference, but not enough for the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a 4.7uF capacitor from pin2 (top end of 10uF) to vcc
reduce the timing resistors by one third.

this way the capacitor pair  will power up as about 1/3 VCC and the pulses will go from there all coming out at about the same size,

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just threw in another 10uF capacitor into the circuit where you said (I don't have a 4.7uF capacitor around) without changing the resistors and I am getting pulses of the same length. Great answer.